# Large dataset - no error - but it wont run - python memory issue?

Tags: python, numpy

So I am trying to run various large images which gets put into an array using numpy so that I can then do some calculations. The calculations get done per image and the opening and closing of each image is done in a loop. I a have reached a frustration point because I have no errors in the code (well none to my knowledge nor any that python is complaining about), and as a matter of fact my code runs for one loop, and then it simply does not run for the second, third, or other loops.

I get no errors! No memory error, no syntax error, no nothing. I have used Spyder and even IDLE, and it simply runs all the calculations sometimes only for one image, sometimes for two, then it just quits the loop (again WITH NO ERROR) as if it had completed running for all images (when it has only ran for one/two images).

I am assuming its a  memory error? - I mean it runs one loop , sometimes two, but never the rest? -- so ...

I have attempted to clear the tracebacks using this:

`sys.exc_clear() 
sys.exc_traceback = sys.last_traceback = None`

I have also even tried to delete each variable when I am done with it 
ie. del variable

However, nothing seems to fix it -- 
Any ideas of what could be wrong would be appreciated!

Comment: Show your code and what seems not to be working. We cannot answer without seeing the problem.

Comment: you should put up some code

Comment: I have experienced similar issues when I've been working with large datasets. My theory is that a malloc fails in a c module when the process is close to the 2 gb limit (32 bit python version), and this goes uncaught by the interpreter.

Comment: Everything seems to work. I have one more function that runs perfectly fine before it, once it reaches this second function it simply exits (as i mentioned). However, when I run the second function alone before the first function the code runs perfectly fine without exiting.  

@ilmarinen: This sounds like it could definately be. Do you happen to know a way of fixing it? -- THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: If each image is independent from the others, you could use the multiprocessing library to spread the load over many processes and then aggregate the results in your main process.

Answer (score 0):

The exit code of the python process should reveal the reason for the process exiting. In the event of an adverse condition, the exit code will be something other than 0. If you are running in a Bash shell or similar, you can run "echo $?" in your shell after running Python to see its exit status.

If the exit status is indeed 0, try putting some print statements in your code to trace the execution of your program. In any case, you would do well to post your code for better feedback.

Good luck!